# Bar Chart Using Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a list of pairs.

**Example:**

```
pair1=[(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(x,y)....]
```

In Python i need to generate a bar chart using `matplotlib` such that if `x` and `y` co-ordinates are same in a pair the bar chart should come to the maximum extent or else in case of `(x,y)` they are different and hence the bar chart should be at the 0 level. So please do help me out with the code in Python.

Comment: Literally the first hit on google. http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find out which pairs equal and generate a list of those results. This list can then be plotted using `matplotlib.pyplot.bar`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pair1=[("a","a"),("2",2),("b","b"),("c","c"),("x","y")]

f = lambda t: t[0] == t[1]
y= list(map(f, pair1))

plt.bar(range(len(y)), y)
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: how to add scrolling bar to this if the series is long, equal spacing between 2 adjacent bars, same colour and printing the x value  exaclty below its bar and removing the y ticks....do help me ..since I m new to Python

Comment: This is not a code writing service. While the code already has most of those features in, for each of the questions there are answers around somewhere. Scrollbars are not easy, you may start looking at a scrollbar for [QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page), 
[wxpython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559270/matplotlib-scrolling-plot)
or using a [SliderWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668454/matplotlib-scroll-bar)

Comment: WTF if you dont know please .. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Sure I know it. I wrote for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page). You may copy it and use it if you like.

Comment: but where can i include the above code of urs there