# Bar chart using matplotlib for repeated words in a column

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have following set of data in CSV format

```
Name    Place
A   India
B   USA
C   India
D   USA
E   China
F   UK
G   Canada
H   China
I   UK
J   UK
```

Following is the code I used,

```
output2.to_csv("Place.csv", index = False)
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
place_plot=output2.plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
fig = place_plot.get_figure()
```

Outout2 -> CSV file.

I need to plot a graph using Python so that it will show the count of people from different country, as shown in the picture

[image: count]

How do I do it?

Comment: I think you forgot to include a problem description (see [ask]) in your question. What you want is a *bar chart*. Searching for this gives you a huge amount of examples. Without you explaining in detail what the problem of implementing any of those is, this question should probably be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bar Chart Using Matplotlib in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895602/bar-chart-using-matplotlib-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you want is this:

```
output2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

assuming `output2` is a `Pandas Dataframe`, which is not clear from your question.

Comment: No its not a Dataframe, output2 is a CSV file where the above data is present. I need to plot a Bar graph(repeated place) for "Place" column in the output2.csv file.

Comment: well it looks like a DataFrame. I don't know other object having the `.to_csv` and `.plot` method. And the code I propose produces exactly what you want. So, if it's really not a Dataframe, I suggest you use `output2 = pd.read_csv("Place.csv")` before the above mentioned code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Following is my code, problem is, the graph is getting closed immediately after i execute the program. Can you help me with this?    
import pandas
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib


df2 =pandas.read_csv('Place.csv')
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
place_plot= df2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=df2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
fig = place_plot.get_figure()

Comment: Edit your question, format it well, remove all unnecessary parts (`display.mpl`, `get_figure`). Your code should contain 1 line for, 1 line for reading the file, 1 line for plotting, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: `df2 =pandas.read_csv('c:\\CSVTOKML\\barcharttrail1.csv')`
place_plot= df2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=df2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
`fig = place_plot.get_figure() `

Comment: Above code displays the graph for 2 seconds and graph disappears and if I dont use `fig = place_plot.get_figure()`  nothing gets displayed.

Comment: This is the comment section. Modify your initial question (at the top of the page).