# Interactive plot update for data-points over time

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataset of 3D-Coordinates mooving around in time. So my ndarray data looks like this:

```py
points = [  # 1st dim: Time-step (/timeframe)
          [  # 2nd dim: Different Objects
           [  # 3rd dim: The coordinates of the Objects
            2.115, 2.387, 3.3680003],
           [2.059, 2.302, 3.2610002],
           [2.1720002 2.2280002 3.1880002]],
          [[1.9530001, 2.306, 3.5760002],  
           [1.9510001, 2.265, 3.433    ],
           [2.1000001, 2.2440002, 3.381]],
          [[1.6760001, 2.459, 3.4650002], 
           [1.5710001, 2.434, 3.367    ],
           [1.6320001 2.4320002 3.2250001]]]
```

I am plotting the objects one after another with:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for timeframe in range(points.shape[0]):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    x_coordinates = points[timeframe][:, 0]
    y_coordinates = points[timeframe][:, 1]
    z_coordinates = points[timeframe][:, 2]
    ax.scatter(x_coordinates, y_coordinates, z_coordinates, c='r', marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

Now I want to make a plot or a Window, where I can use a slider to choose between the plotted figures depending on the timestep.

#### Is there any code or python module, which is used to choose a plot in a for loop e.g. via slider?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668504/6934388) shows how to use a slider to interactively update a plot. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use matplotlib widgets library, but for that you need to have your matplotlib interactive.

You can add a horizontal slider (see example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html) and when you select and move the slider you call a function.
In the example I provided you, that function is called `update`.
When you update the slider value by moving it, it calls this function and gives the actual slider value to it.

So you could create a slider with the integers value of your `for loop` and when you update the slider you call the `update` function and inside it you have the code to plot the data using that integer value that came from the slider.

**Slider**:

```
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
freq_slider = Slider(
    ax=axfreq,
    label='Time Steps',
    valmin=0, # minimun value of range
    valmax=points.shape[0] - 1, # maximum value of range
    valinit=0,
    valstep=1.0 # step between values
)
```

I keept almost all names to help when you see the example I shared.
Take notice that I added `valstep=1.0` to increase by 1 when you slide the slider.

**Update Function**:

```
def update(val)

    val = int(val) # it must be an integer

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    x_coordinates = points[val][:, 0]
    y_coordinates = points[val][:, 1]
    z_coordinates = points[val][:, 2]
    ax.scatter(x_coordinates, y_coordinates, z_coordinates, c='r', marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

It may arrise some issues because you may not have your matplotlib interactive.
If you are using jupyter-notebook is very easy to put it interactive, you just need to add this line on top:

```
%matplotlib widget
```

if it doens't work you can try:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

you may also need to install some aditional modules.

If you want it to come back to normal, you just need to add again on the top:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Further information on interactive plots in matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html